# Уточнение и запятые

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение в нашей местной газете со следующими знаками препинания: Восьмого апреля 2015 года в прокуратуру района поступило обращение гражданина Н о нахождении в аварийном состоянии кирпичной кладки стены, являющейся несущей для опоры плит перекрытия, перед входом в дом № 27, по улице Советской, в с.Алтунино Вачского района, где расположено помещение почты.(Нужны ли запятые после номера дома, названия улицы; разве здесь уточнение?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, здесь вообще вопрос не стоит, уточнение оно или нет. Здесь конструкция "дом по улице такой-то", т.е. предложное управление. Единое целое, выкинуть какую-либо часть фрагмента невозможно.

Тут еще другое. "заявление о нахождении кладки" означает, что гражданин обнаружил кладку. Долго искал - обнаружил. По указанному адресу в аварийном состоянии. Извините, но контекст совершенно исключает подобную трактовку. а значит приходится опять говорить о неполной адекватности журналиста, корректора или самого редактора - кто там у них подобные перлы рожает.

Я еще думаю, что и запятая после перекрытия тоже лишняя. "Перекрытие перед входом в дом", а не "[чем-то там являющаяся] стена перед в входом в дом". Последнее было бы забавно. Так что еще один перл.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемый вариант

Восьмого апреля 2015 года в прокуратуру района поступило обращение гражданина Н. о нахождении в аварийном состоянии кирпичной кладки стены, являющейся несущей опорой для плит перекрытия перед входом в дом № 27, по улице Советской, в с.Алтунино Вачского района, где расположено помещение почты.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Здесь отличительным признаком является номер дома, где обнаружена неисправность, а остальные координаты даны как уточняющие.

Вообще-то уточняющий ряд должен отделяться паузой/тире, но для  канцелярского стиля лучше подходят запятые.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Другой вариант (убираем запятые, все обстоятельства считаем неоднородными, они будут обозначать координаты проблемного дома, взятые в районном масштабе):

Восьмого апреля 2015 года в прокуратуру района поступило обращение гражданина Н. о нахождении в аварийном состоянии кирпичной кладки стены, являющейся несущей опорой для плит перекрытия перед входом в дом № 27 по улице Советской в с.Алтунино Вачского района, где расположено помещение почты.

А вообще говоря, здесь возможно авторское решение, вы можете оставить вариант, который вам больше нравится.

Comment: То есть запятые оставить так? Но уточнение должно сужать понятие, или же здесь уточняется местонахождение дома №27? Все-таки мне кажется, что после №  дома запятая не нужна.